# Reading only one Excel book into R

Tags: r, operating-system

I am working with an Excel file. It has 3 books. I need help with extracting only one of the books into R. I did a Google search and could not glean the solution from the information. I am working on a MacBook; I am running the latest version of R.

More specifically, here is the question.

The data set has three workbooks "Sales", "Resources", and "Supplies".  How do you read in only the items from the "Sales" workbook?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean worksheet when you say workbook, no?

Comment: [readxl::read_excel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/) function has `sheet` option.

Comment: Terminology is important regardless of discipline and is even more important when working in a forum like this. Excel _workbooks_ contain _worksheets_. That's an important distinction (you can see the use of wrong terminology caused some confusion already). Finally, use `readxl::read_excel()` and specify the _worksheet_ index in the salient parameter. But, virtually all Excel-file reading packages have a function that takes a sheet name or index to target for reading. I'm curious as to what (if any) real research you did to not see said options.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to the R language. And I am not too well versed with Excel. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way, is to save the worksheet you need as csv, and use `read.csv` in `R`. but if you prefer to read directly the excel file:

Use the package `XLConnect`

```
df <- readWorksheetFromFile("excel_file.xlsx", sheet = "Sales")
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion and the suggestion from the first person who responded.